# Problem with Image resizing inside Column Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following code snippet,

```
GridTile(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child:  Image.network(imageUrl, fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,),
        ),
        ),
    );
```

producing following output..

[image]

But when I add column to my card like this...

```
GridTile(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
               Image.network(imageUrl, fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,),
          ],
        ),
        ),
    );
```

I got the below overflow issue..
[image]

What am I missing here., Is there any important layout details about Column that I need to take care of. I need column so that I can add favorite button and product description below the image. Find below the parent widget for reference.

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Shopify'),
    ),
    body: GridView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ProductItem(dummyProducts[index].title, dummyProducts[index].imageUrl),
      itemCount: dummyProducts.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Please adjust the gridDelegate, try to change: childAspectRatio: 1 and see what happend.

Comment: childAspectRatio of 1.5 was too large. As you said I kept childAspectRatio to 1 which was little better. Still I faced overflow issue. Then I wrapped my image in Aspect Ratio did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclosing the image in AspectRatio finally did the trick. Please find the code below.

```
GridTile(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
                child: Image.network(imageUrl, fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your images have a determined proportion (width / height ratio).

Using `gridDelegate` with `childAspectRatio` you can assign the ratio of the `GridTile` inside your `GridView`.

Adjust the `childAspectRatio` or adjust the **images ratio**.

Play with this number to see the effect:

```
childAspectRatio: 1    // square
childAspectRatio: 2    // horizontal rectangle
childAspectRatio: 0.5  // vertical rectangle
```

Comment: childAspectRatio resizes the overall grid tile so I kept it as 1 to make it square and wrap the image in AspectRatio widget to achieve the result. Thank you